# how to load sql datasource before select item value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datasource

I have SQL dataSource  on my asp.net page and I had this error when page is loading

'ddlTypes' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

```
private void GetQueryString(Uri tempUri)
{
    if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("IntrestFocus") != null)
    {
        ddlTopics.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("IntrestFocus"); 
    }

    else
        if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Skills") != null)
        {
            ddlSkills.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Skills"); 
        }
    else
        if(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Type") != null)
        {
            ddlTypes.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Type"); 
        }

}
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSTypes" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Types]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


                <asp:DropDownList CssClass="selectpicker mobile-stack select-type" data-style="lts-white font-black drop-shadow select-height" ID="ddlTypes" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDSTypes" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select a Type</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Have you verified the value being set to the SelectedValue property is in deed in the list of values of items bound to it???  Could you post the client-side markup of the dropdown only?  Also, there are 3 ddl's here,which one causes the error?

Comment: to bind dropdownlist I use asp:SqlDataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your primary option:

```
private void GetQueryString(Uri tempUri)
{
  ddlTopics.DataSource = SqlDSTypes.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
  ddlTopics.DataBind();

  //Put your logic here, behind databind ...
  if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("IntrestFocus") != null)
  {
      ddlTopics.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("IntrestFocus"); 
  }

  else
      if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Skills") != null)
      {
        ddlSkills.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Skills"); 
      }
  else
      if(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Type") != null)
      {
        ddlTypes.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Type"); 
      }

}
```

Also make sure the DataSourceID is not set, when you choose the above answer.

There is, however, another possibility, that is using the `OnDataBound` event and put your `DropDownList` logic therein. It will be fired after the `DropDownList` is databound then:

Your code behind:

```
protected function ddlTopics_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Put your logic here, behind databind ...
  if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("IntrestFocus") != null)
  {
      ddlTopics.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("IntrestFocus"); 
  }

  else
      if (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Skills") != null)
      {
        ddlSkills.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Skills"); 
      }
  else
      if(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Type") != null)
      {
        ddlTypes.SelectedValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tempUri.Query).Get("Type"); 
      }  
}
```

Your aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTopics" OnDataBound="ddlTopics_DataBound" runat="server" ...
```

The latter is probably the neatest option.